# Max memory used by the SELECT query used to populate a materialized view

Tags: clickhouse

is there a specific parameter to set the maximum amount of memory Clickhouse can use when running the SELECT query to populate a materialized view? Or does Clickhouse enforce the same memory limit it uses for conventional SELECT queries?

Is there a metric that tracks the memory used to fill in a materialized view? If not, can I use the uncompressed size of level 0 recent parts in the aggregating merge tree as an estimate? I would expect that, if a part I just inserted is 10Mb uncompressed, the SELECT query should not have taken more memory than that approximatively.

Context:
Version: 21.8.13.1.altinitystable

I have a MergeTree table, an AggregatingMergeTree and a materialized view to populate the AggregatingMergeTree with the content of the MergeTree. The schemas are [here](https://gist.github.com/fpacifici/bbd99d558006f5fb6a0aa32a07ccc0dc), but I think that should not really matter.

So I am trying to find out what the limit will be before Clickhouse will reject writes and if there is a way to monitor how much memory my inserts are taking in memory in the current state.

Thank you

Comment: Clickhouse enforce the same memory limit it uses for conventional INSERT queries

Comment: See system.query_log and system.query_views_log

Comment: ah interesting. I did not expect those queries to show up in the query_log. Thanks.